# Weekline Plugin Not Displaying Clicked Weekdays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm trying to integrate this weekline plugin but it seems not be working.
Everything seems fine as I see no jquery error in my console but the weekdays don't show on my input field when clicked on. All other jquery codes are working perfectly.

Below is my code
Jquery:
$("#weekCal").weekLine();

```
      // Return selected days as labels
         $("#weekCal2").weekLine({
                mousedownSel: false,
                onChange: function () {
                        $("#kid_pickup_days").html(
                                $(this).weekLine('setSelected')
                        );
                }
         });
```

In the html, I have a span with id="weekCal" which shows the weekdays to be selected and an input field with id="kid_pickup_days" which is supposed to show the weekday as input value when selected, but doesn't.

Any suggestion/solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: The '2' in #weekCal2 is intentional, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's used to return weekday as label, there's option for 1 which returns weekday as index, and so on

Answer (score 1):

You Should try this;

```
$("#weekCal2").weekLine({
                    mousedownSel: false,
                    onChange: function () {
                            $("#kid_pickup_days").html(
                                    $(this).weekLine('getSelected')
                            );
                    }
             });
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Kathiriya but that's exactly the code I posted above with the question which isn't working.

Comment: sorry my man this code is different your write "setSelected" and i have wrote "getSelected" insted of "setSelected".

Comment: Ok @Ankit Kathiriya, just tried and it still did not work . . .thanks, do appreciate your input